# apache2 starting fault

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

I cannot access to my website, its unavailable i dont know why, apache2 seems run, but in the log:

```
[Mon Feb 04 00:43:23 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.5 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Feb 04 01:05:01 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Feb 04 01:05:03 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.5 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations

root@mbcloud:~# a2enmod php5
Module php5 already enabled
```

Comment: What is the output of `netstat -laputen` command? What is your apache configuration file? (/etc/apache2/sites-available) have you enabled your site? What is the content of /etc/apache2/ports.conf?

Answer (score 1):

The log is perfectly normal your apache was restarted.  Your problem lies elsewhere and you haven't provided sufficient information to diagnose it.